# How to buffer flush output to the browser in webapp2?

Tags: python, html, webapp2

We would like to show real time HTML output for a long running process on a web page but webapp2 is holding all of our HTML output to the browser until the class handling methods return.

In Perl, we used to use:

> $| = 1;

...to force stdout output to the browser as processes were running.

We have been searching for a Python webapp2 equivalent but have been unable to find an override so our self.response.write('') commands show up in the browser as we print them.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that app engine does not support streaming response https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Responses.

see if app engine Task Queue is suitable for your requirement https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue